# Using SSL certificate issued by Godaddy for localhost website

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, ssl, godaddy

I have a Godaddy SSL certificate that i want to use on `localhost`, however the certificate is issued to `example.com` and if i use that it definitely gives a certificate mismatch error. Is there any workaround to use it for `localhost` without having to go through the certificate error on any user? and the website is intranet based and would be accessed by other users using this `https://<publicip>/appdesk` or `https://localhost/appdesk` & i need it to bypass the certificate warning or error automatically not manually that the user has to click everytime through to allow website access.

**Update**

I did try by issuing the certificate on the hostname itself but it too displays the certificate mismatch error.There are lot of computers accessing the server though publicip and cannot add the hostname to host file in every computer. Is there any way i can issue certificate directly to sub-directories like `appdesk` to avoid the mismatch error, so that accessing `https://localhost/appdesk` or `https://192.168.1.0/appdesk` doesn't show any error.

Answer (score 3):

You either:

- Connect to the the fully qualified hostname used in the certificate
- Don't use HTTPS for connections to localhost
- Generate a self-signed certificate that is valid for localhost

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I did generated a self-signed certificate for this, but when other computers in the network try to connect to this `localhost` website we are getting the certification mismatch error. Any resolution for this?

Comment: @SyedZoheb what you are saying makes zero sense! If other connect to localhost, how do they get a mismatch error? localhost = localhost. It's by definition not a mismatch.

Comment: @Daniel Please see the update in the question, while accessing from outside, we are using `https://<publicip>/appdesk` and not `https://localhost/appdesk` this is where the error occurs and i am looking some resolution for it